# Google Market API Issue

Tags: android, google-play

I'm using an unofficial version of Google Market API to extract out details of the apps from here : http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/
However, the problem seems to be that no matter what my search query string is, I get the same results. 
Has anyone used this/ any thoughts on this?
Please let me know!

Thanks
Thothathri